# Find index of a pair of value in array with matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, indexing

I've 2 values and I would like to find them in a array.
This values have the same index

Example:

```
0 0
1 2
2 3
4 5
```

I'm looking for (1,2) so the index is 2

Comment: Please explain how you get to `2` from your example data. It is not clear.

Comment: here is the original array [link](http://pro.ellip6.com/SebastienForum/Array.jpg) the pair I'm looking for are in the column 2 and 3

Comment: Please, edit your question to clarify that you are looking for the starting index of a sequence of values. Also, amend your example to be consistent with the question. In your case, the index will be 3 (or rephrase the question).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
M = [[0 0]; [1 2]; [2 3]; 4 5]

ex = [1, 2]

[~ r] = ismember(ex,M, 'rows')
```

I think this is what you're after.

If you're not looking to match the whole row but just columns 2 and 3 then:

```
[~, r] = ismember(ex, M(:,2:3), 'rows')
```

Comment: M is not really my array see the link  [link](http://pro.ellip6.com/SebastienForum/Array.jpg) I'm looking in the colum 2 and 3

Comment: ex(1) is in column 3 and ex(2) in column 2. If I try your code :   [~ r] = ismember(pos, s(:,3:2), 'rows') I've this error : "An array for multiple LHS assignement cannot contain expression"

Comment: @user2724407 try `s(:,[3,2])`, you can't just go `3:2` in Matlab. You could go `3:-1:2` though

Comment: I've the same error with [~ r] = ismember(pos, s(:,[3,2]), 'rows')

Comment: @user2724407 ok maybe it's becuase I left off the comma on the LHS. Try `[~, r] = ...`

Comment: should be `ismember(M(:,2:3), ex, 'rows')` (inverse input A and B)

Comment: @Magla no they are in the correct order in my example. Using my way I get `r == 2` where you would get `r == [0;1;0;0]`

Comment: it works fine with [~ ,r] = ismember(s(:,[3,2]), pos, 'rows') but I've multiple value ( from index 10 to 19 for example) . I think it is precision problem . Is the value taken from the plot (it show only 0,7706 )have the same precision as the data from my array : 0,770650948555785

Comment: Finally it works , the mistake is that I've multiple same value in my log   Thanks you for your help

Answer (score 0):

find(example(1:end-1)==val(1) & example(2:end) ==val(2))

or if you have the right tool box (econ?) use lagmatrix and bsxfun to compare entire rows.

Comment: 2 is the index of the pair I'm looking for